# I am trying to open a drawer on the press of an icon, inside of a sticky header I have created in a flutter app

Tags: flutter, header, drawer

So I created a sticky header that goes from page to page and I really like the design.

[image: App header]

I am trying to make the hamburger icon on the left open a drawer. Below is my class widget. I have tried:
onpress: () {Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();},

I have tried turning the Container into a Scaffold, I can't keep its appearance when I make it a scaffold, and I have tried making a GlobalKey. But every where I find says that it needs to be a Scaffold for the Global key to work. is there anyway I could make a Scaffold inside of this Container because I tried to put the Container in a Scaffold and that didn't work either.

Also my main.dart imports the file this is made on and then calls the class inside the MyApp class. Thanks for the help.

```js
class HeaderWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      color: headerBackGroundColor,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          // Menu icon
          IconButton(
            iconSize: 24,
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.menu,
              color: headerMenuIconColor,
              semanticLabel: 'Main menu for navigating app.',
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                  SnackBar(content: Text('Menu icon button was pressed')));
            },
            tooltip: "Select an option from the menu.",
          ),
          // Search icon
          IconButton(
            iconSize: 24,
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: headerSearchIconColor,
              semanticLabel: 'Search the app.',
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                  SnackBar(content: Text('Search icon button was pressed')));
            },
            tooltip: "Enter a search term.",
          ),
          // Share icon
          IconButton(
            iconSize: 24,
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.share,
              color: headerShareIconColor,
              semanticLabel: 'Share this page from the app.',
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                  SnackBar(content: Text('Share icon button was pressed')));
            },
            tooltip: "Share this content.",
          ),
          // Weather icon
          IconButton(
            iconSize: 24,
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.cloud,
              color: headerWeatherIconColor,
              semanticLabel:
                  'Weather widget with temperature and sky conditions.',
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                  SnackBar(content: Text('Weather icon button was pressed')));
            },
            tooltip: "Set weather options.",
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT:
I guess I am doing something wrong. The following is my header.dart:

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'app_config.dart';

final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
        child: HeaderWidget(),
      ),
      drawer: const Drawer(child: Center(child: Text('Drawer'))),
      body: const Center(child: Text('Example Page')),
    );
  }
}

class HeaderWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      color: headerBackGroundColor,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          // Menu icon
          IconButton(
            iconSize: 24,
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.menu,
              color: headerMenuIconColor,
              semanticLabel: 'Main menu for navigating app.',
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              scaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer();

            },
            tooltip: "Select an option from the menu.",
          ),
          // Search icon
          IconButton(
            iconSize: 24,
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: headerSearchIconColor,
              semanticLabel: 'Search the app.',
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                  SnackBar(content: Text('Search icon button was pressed')));
            },
            tooltip: "Enter a search term.",
          ),
          // Share icon
          IconButton(
            iconSize: 24,
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.share,
              color: headerShareIconColor,
              semanticLabel: 'Share this page from the app.',
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                  SnackBar(content: Text('Share icon button was pressed')));
            },
            tooltip: "Share this content.",
          ),
          // Weather icon
          IconButton(
            iconSize: 24,
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.cloud,
              color: headerWeatherIconColor,
              semanticLabel:
                  'Weather widget with temperature and sky conditions.',
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                  SnackBar(content: Text('Weather icon button was pressed')));
            },
            tooltip: "Set weather options.",
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then I call it in my main.dart

```js
import 'header.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage(
      {super.key, required this.bootStrapInfo, required this.myAppDefines});
  final BootStrapInfo bootStrapInfo;
  final AppDefines myAppDefines;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(AppConfig.appName),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              HeaderWidget(),
              SplashWidget(),
              // Body Container
              Expanded(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
```

I can not get a key to work at all. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

### Try using a global key

Declare a scaffold state global key:

```dart
final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

Assign it to a scaffold, must have a drawer set as well:

```dart
...

Scaffold(
  key: scaffoldKey,
  drawer: Drawer(),

...
```

Open it like so:

```dart
scaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer();
```

---

### Full example with HeaderWidget in question

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Page(),
    );
  }
}

final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      appBar: const PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
        child: HeaderWidget(),
      ),
      drawer: const Drawer(child: Center(child: Text('Drawer'))),
      body: const Center(child: Text('Example Page')),
    );
  }
}

class HeaderWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const HeaderWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      color: headerBackGroundColor,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          // Menu icon
          IconButton(
            iconSize: 24,
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.menu,
              color: headerMenuIconColor,
              semanticLabel: 'Main menu for navigating app.',
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              scaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer();
            },
            tooltip: "Select an option from the menu.",
          ),
          // Search icon
          IconButton(
            iconSize: 24,
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: headerSearchIconColor,
              semanticLabel: 'Search the app.',
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                  content: Text('Search icon button was pressed')));
            },
            tooltip: "Enter a search term.",
          ),
          // Share icon
          IconButton(
            iconSize: 24,
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.share,
              color: headerShareIconColor,
              semanticLabel: 'Share this page from the app.',
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                  content: Text('Share icon button was pressed')));
            },
            tooltip: "Share this content.",
          ),
          // Weather icon
          IconButton(
            iconSize: 24,
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.cloud,
              color: headerWeatherIconColor,
              semanticLabel:
                  'Weather widget with temperature and sky conditions.',
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                  content: Text('Weather icon button was pressed')));
            },
            tooltip: "Set weather options.",
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

## Try this:

### Example using a custom scaffold page as parent

my_scaffold.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'header_widget.dart';

final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

class MyScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget body;
  const MyScaffold({super.key, required this.body});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      drawer: const Drawer(child: Center(child: Text('Drawer'))),
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
        child: HeaderWidget(scaffoldKey: _scaffoldKey),
      ),
      body: body,
    );
  }
}
```

header_widget.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HeaderWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey;

  const HeaderWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.scaffoldKey,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      color: headerBackGroundColor,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          // Menu icon
          IconButton(
            iconSize: 24,
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.menu,
              color: headerMenuIconColor,
              semanticLabel: 'Main menu for navigating app.',
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              scaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer();
            },
            tooltip: "Select an option from the menu.",
          ),
          // Search icon
          IconButton(
            iconSize: 24,
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: headerSearchIconColor,
              semanticLabel: 'Search the app.',
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                  content: Text('Search icon button was pressed')));
            },
            tooltip: "Enter a search term.",
          ),
          // Share icon
          IconButton(
            iconSize: 24,
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.share,
              color: headerShareIconColor,
              semanticLabel: 'Share this page from the app.',
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                  content: Text('Share icon button was pressed')));
            },
            tooltip: "Share this content.",
          ),
          // Weather icon
          IconButton(
            iconSize: 24,
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.cloud,
              color: headerWeatherIconColor,
              semanticLabel:
                  'Weather widget with temperature and sky conditions.',
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                  content: Text('Weather icon button was pressed')));
            },
            tooltip: "Set weather options.",
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

MyHomePage should look like this:

```dart
// import my_scaffold.dart

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    super.key,
    required this.bootStrapInfo,
    required this.myAppDefines,
  });

  final BootStrapInfo bootStrapInfo;
  final AppDefines myAppDefines;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyScaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
              SplashWidget(),
              // Body Container
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate? The header is in a return Container( "See code" so when I add

scaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer();

I get: Undefined name 'scaffoldKey'.

and if I change my current return to a Scaffold it stops liking my padding, color, and alignment.

Comment: The global key goes anywhere in a file outside of classes and functions where it can be called. The scaffold is the page where the drawer is. See example added in the answer.

Comment: So your answer works as long as my HeaderWidget class is built in the main.dart file. I have it in its own file so I can use it for every page/subpage that I have. And as soon as I move it back to its own file it stops working. I made an edit on my question with this answer implemented.

Comment: No! It doesn't matter where the it is. Let's try again: Is the `HeaderWidget` the same everywhere it's used? Does every page have it's own `Drawer`? If not, It may be better to make a parent widget that holds the header and drawer and have child pages.

Comment: you are correct. Not every page has its own Drawer, I was trying to limit that function to just the HeaderWidget. Also I changed the home page class so that HeaderWidget is called as a child inside the appBar but other pages still have it in the body: Center( child: Column( children: [ HeaderWidget(),

Comment: Added another example to answer: using a custom scaffold as a parent page.

Comment: I finally got it figured out!! There is one major change that I had to make to your code to get it to work right. Everywhere I had to call HeaderWidget() I had to change to HeaderWidget(scaffoldKey: scaffoldKey) and somewhere on the file I hade to call final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>(); So your answer got me there eventually! Thank you so much!!!